# Star convection gradient dependencies

Tags: astrophysics, stars, convection

In star convection you can work with radiative and adiabatic temperature gradients, that for example the radiative one can be defined as,

$$\nabla_{rad}=\frac{3\kappa L P}{16 \pi a c G m T^4}$$

This can be seen for example in this [source](http://astronomy.nmsu.edu/jasonj/565/docs/10_29.pdf). Here they put emphasis in the dependency of luminosity $L$ and mass $m$ with radius, i.e. $L=L(r)$ and $m=m(r)$. But otherwise for the other star variables is not specified,

- $\kappa$ the opacity
- $P$ the pressure
- $T$ the temperature

As is not specified, my doubt is if this variables are used as radius dependent ones or fixed values. In this case what variable should I use? The star-center values, or the surface values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The opacity, pressure and temperature all vary as a function of position in a star. For a spherically symmetric star you can assume they vary only as a function of the radial coordinate $r$.

The reason that luminosity and mass are written as $L(r)$ and $m(r)$ is to remind us that these do vary with radial coordinate and avoid confusion with the luminosity and mass *of the entire star*, which are meaningful and observable quantities. $L_* = L(R)$ and $M_* = m(R)$ respectively, where $R$ is the radius of the star.